# Copying data from one address to another using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, arm, memory-address

I am trying to move a halfword i.e 16 bits from one memory address of my microcontroller to another using C. Please have a look at my simple code below:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void){

    int16_t *src = (int16_t*)0x20000000; //source memory address
    int16_t *dst = (int16_t*)0x20000016; //destination memory address
    *dst = *src; //dereference both, set destination value to source value
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as I hit the line `*dst = *src`, I run into a Hardfault exception. My low understanding of pointers and dereference/reference could be the problem. I would appreciate some help.

EDIT:
Is there any way I can write this in a single line of code using the assignment operator (=)?

Comment: Have you tried marking `src` and `dst` as `volatile`? Also, I believe that having two named variables is way cleaner compared to doing this in a single line of code.

Comment: is `memcpy` an option?

Comment: Are you sure that the address you want to access is memory-mapped? Some micros use IO-mapped mechanisms to access hardware stuff.

Comment: You might try to split the assignment. First read into some variable then write. This might help identify which part fails. Maybe there are some MMU restrictions on that memory area.

Comment: I tried the suggestions here. Still giving me a hardfault. Is my code implementation correct though?

Comment: assuming, these addresses are legal and not mapped and not read/write protected on yours microcontroller, you should write it in a single line:               " \*((int16_t*)0x20000016)=*((int16_t*)0x20000000);" :)

Comment: @Jspake Does your microcontroller support non aligned reads and writes,  0x20000016 is not 4 byte aligned which I assume your arm requires.

Comment: @Jspake Are you sure that pointer src and dst are pointing to valid memory locations? Also how can you be sure that those memory location pointed to by src and dst contain an int ?

Comment: @Colin__s That is definitely the problem. I was thinking 0x16 in terms of decimal. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Michael Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: @user7375520 Yes I was sure they are valid. I stored a random int in the source address (0x20000000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a write to `0x20000016`, which isn't on a 4 byte boundry. If your processor doesn't support unaligned reads and writes this would cause a fault. What processor are you using?

Comment: I am using the ARM Cortex M0 processor.